# Access to the coordinates from an address swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

Hi how can I access to the longitude and latitude parameters outside of this block ?

```
 let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
        geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address) { placemarks, error in
           let placemark = placemarks?.first
           let lat = placemark?.location?.coordinate.latitude
           let lon = placemark?.location?.coordinate.longitude
           print("Lat: \(lat), Lon: \(lon)")
        }
```

I want to save this two params as Float or String in firebase. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a function like this:

```
func getLatAndLong(address : String, competion : @escaping (CLLocationCoordinate2D?) -> ()) {
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address) { placemarks, error in
        let placemark = placemarks?.first
        let lat = placemark?.location?.coordinate.latitude
        let lon = placemark?.location?.coordinate.longitude
        print("Lat: \(lat), Lon: \(lon)")
        competion(placemark?.location?.coordinate)
    }
}
```

and then call it as :

```
var location : CLLocationCoordinate2D?
getLatAndLong(address: "pass your address here") { (coordinates) in
        self.location = coordinates
}
```

Now your `location` variable holds the value.

you can use it to get latitide and longitude

```
let latitide = location?.latitude
let longitude = location?.longitude
```

---

**Option 2**

You can declare a variable in class and update its you value once you get the coordinates. I would suggest using the above approach as geocoder runs asynchronously. Its better to use a completion handler to know when the geoCoder has finished executing the task and has got the location.

```
var latitude = 0.0 // 
var longitude = 0.0

let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
geocoder.geocodeAddressString("address") { placemarks, error in
    let placemark = placemarks?.first
    self.latitude = placemark?.location?.coordinate.latitude ?? 0.0
    self.longitude = placemark?.location?.coordinate.longitude ?? 0.0
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and your response ! Do you know if it's possible to cast them in `Float`?

Comment: If you want store lat , long in firebase then you can add as single string like `let locationCoordinates = "\(latitude),\(longitude)"` and better to use as single string not float

Comment: But then will I be able to separe them ?

Comment: @SauceCurry to convert them to float, just do let `let newLatitude = Float(location?.latitude ?? 0.0)`

Comment: @SauceCurry yes you can separate them